Bounced Emails and Email Verification
With active bounce management, I get information like this near the email address.

Using Classic, I get this additional email confirmation link.

This leads me to this dialog.

The "Bounce Email" dialog does not seem to exist in Lightning. And the link says "Confirm Email Address" while it really only seems to remove the bounce information. Is my assumption correct? Is there any standard functionality that resembles a "confirmed email address" that I can also query by its own field? Like an email where you click a link to confirm your email address. The only information I could find so far was relating to users only.
